# FindFit not giving a good fit despite good initial parameters

Tags: fitting, data

I'm having a problem with `FindFit` not giving a good fit to my [data](http://ge.tt/2dssAr81/v/0?c), even though the initial parameters I give look really good when plotted. The fitting function is

```
P1[Ω_, Δ_, t_] := 
  ((Ω/Sqrt[Ω^2 + Δ^2])*Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[Ω^2 + Δ^2]*t])^2;

fitfunction[Ω_, Δ_, t_, a_, b_, c_] := 
  a + b*P1[Ω, Δ + c, t];
```

and I give the approximate starting parameters:

```
centrepeak = -91;
Ωapprox = 2 π 29 10^3;
amplitude = 0.8;
offset = 0.13;
pulsetime = 16 10^-6;
```

Then I fit using `FindFit`:

```
rabifit = 
 FindFit[scandata,
   {fitfunction[Ω, Δ, pulsetime, voffset, amp, hoffset],
    amp < 1, amp > 0, voffset > 0, voffset < 0.5 },
   {{Ω, Ωapprox}, {amp, amplitude}, {voffset, offset}, {hoffset, centrepeak}}, Δ]
```

which gives

```
{Ω -> 187398., amp -> 0.216895, voffset -> 0.136962, hoffset -> 93.5922}
```

If I plot the fitting function with my starting parameters (red line) and the fitted parameters (orange line) against the data I get the following graph:

[image: Plot of data and fitting function for the initial parameters (red) and the fitted parameters (orange)]

As it can be seen the initial parameters seem to give a much better fit than the fitted ones. I've tried various things, e.g., changing the fitting method, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions for anything else I could try?

The code for generating the plot is

```
Show[Plot[{
  fitfunction[Ωapprox, 2 π Δ 10^3, pulsetime, offset, amplitude, 2 π centrepeak 10^3], 
  fitfunction[Ω, 2 π Δ 10^3, pulsetime, voffset, amp, 2 π hoffset 10^3] /. rabifit},
  {Δ, 0, 200},
  PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Orange]}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> 30, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Frequency (kHz)", "Probability in |1>"}, 
  ImageSize -> 30*30], 
 ListPlot[scandata, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.007]]]
```

Comment: Please give the full code for generating the plot. You should use NonlinearModelFit instead of FindFit, since its output is much more convenient...

Comment: It would be helpful if you submitted at least the data that you're fitting. Also, what version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post with the code for generating the plot. The data can be found via the link in the first sentence, I can provide more if necessary. I'm using Mathematica 7.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you plot your function, you are applying scaling factors that you are not passing to FindFit.  For example, you pass a starting guess of `centrepeak` of `-91` when it should be `-2 π 91 10^3`.  Try this

```
scandata = Import["peakdata.csv"];
scandata = Map[{#[[1]], N[ToExpression[#[[2]]]]} &, scandata];

fitfunction[Ω_, Δ_, t_, a_, b_, c_] := 
  a + b*P1[Ω, Δ + c, t];

P1[Ω_, Δ_, t_] := ((Ω/Sqrt[Ω^2 + Δ^2])*Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[Ω^2 + Δ^2]*t])^2.;

Ωapprox = 2 π 29 10^3;
centrepeak = -2 π 91 10^3;
amplitude = 0.8;
offset = 0.13;
pulsetime = 16 10^-6;

rabifit = 
 FindFit[scandata,
  {fitfunction[Ω, 2 π Δ 10^3, pulsetime, voffset, amp, hoffset], 
   amp < 1, amp > 0, voffset > 0, voffset < 0.5},
  {{Ω, Ωapprox}, {amp, amplitude}, {voffset, offset}, {hoffset, centrepeak}},
  Δ, MaxIterations -> 1000]

Show[Plot[{
  fitfunction[Ωapprox, 2 π Δ 10^3, pulsetime, offset, amplitude, centrepeak ],
  fitfunction[Ω, 2 π Δ 10^3, pulsetime, voffset, amp, hoffset ] /. rabifit},
  {Δ, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Orange]}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> 30, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Frequency (kHz)", "Probability in |1>"}, 
  ImageSize -> 30*30], 
 ListPlot[scandata, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.007]]]
```

[image]

Comment: @ssch - You edited my post so that, for example, \[CapitalOmega] was replaced by an actual capital omega.  This is very nice so thank you.  How did you do it please?

Comment: Using this userscript: [Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor)

Comment: @WalkingRandomly - thanks a lot! Should have spotted that myself...